# how to bypass the magiceden cloudflare or how can i get some infos from magiceden?

Tags: node.js, api, axios, cloudflare

I'm gonna get some information such as collection names, collection floor price from magiceden, a solana marketplace.
And I used axios.get function in nodejs project to get this info.
But it worked before Jan 27th 2022, but not work now.
the test code you can see here.

```
axios.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/new_collections", {
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
},
}).then((res) => {
 console.log(res.data);
}).catch((err) => {
 console.log(err.message);
});
```

I saw the returned results, so I can know that Cloudflare returns 403 error.
So I tried to set request header information.
I tried the following header infos.

```
headers: {
 'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
 'if-none-match': 'W/"2666-Zk3Sie7K34jZXASeZMxutI02+C4"',
 'origin': 'https://magiceden.io',
 'referer': 'https://magiceden.io/',
 'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
 'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
 'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
 'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
 'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
 'user-agent': 
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
}
```

But it still doesnt work now.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me without any modifications.

[image: A chrome screenshot showing that the code is working]

You were most likely receiving this error because CloudFlare considered your IP "suspicious" (were you perhaps making the requests too often?). It is very likely that there were more details in the body of the 403 message, like a message saying that you should complete a captcha. For a solution, try looking for such details, change your IP address or perhaps wait some time :)

You cannot "bypass" CloudFlare, that's the entire point of using CloudFlare - that there is to way to bypass it unless the website owners have some misconfiguration.

Perhaps the website owners didn't mean to have such restrictive limits for this specific API? Maybe contacting them to ease the limit could be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the top level domain from `.io` to `.dev`

```
https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/new_collections
```

Comment: This returns only subset of records. For my target collection, for api-mainnet endpoint the `total` returned is 355 while when accessing via `polygon-api.magiceden.io/v2/xc...` total is the true 42k. Also it does not allow you to pass through those 355 with `&skip`.